# How to add rows to an existing Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python, pandas, xlwt

My question is, how to add rows to an existing excel file using Python?

I have a spreadsheet like this:

```
     A      B
0   sam    pam
1   jam    dam
2   nam    vam
```

and I want a result like this:

```
     A      B
0   sam    pam
1   xxx    xxx
2   jam    dam
3   nam    vam
```

So, I want to insert the values `1 xxx xxx` in between the existing rows in the Excel file.

This code below is writing to a particular cell rather than inserting in the space between.

```
if insheet.cell_value(row, 0) == insheet.cell_value(row + 1, 0):
   wb.write(x,w)
```